# Função Plot do igraph - (python)

Tags: python, plot, grafo

Tentei usar a biblioteca do igraph para python a fim de plotar um grafo, usei o próprio exemplo da documentação, porém não deu certo.

Código usado:

```
import igraph
from igraph import plot

g = igraph.Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])
layout = g.layout("kk")
plot(g, layout=layout)
```

Erros retornados:

> line 455, in plot result = Plot(target, bbox,
>   background=kwds.get("background", "white")) line 120, in **init**
>   self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface) line
>   396, in **getattr** raise TypeError("plotting not available")
>   TypeError: plotting not available

Answer (score -3):

Pra mim o que funcionou foi um

```
pip install cairocffi
```

Em todo caso, confere tbm se vc tem as bibliotecas do cairo instaladas.